# "free(): invalid pointer" when calling "libucis.so" on release build (O3), where my code was never reached

Tags: c++

I'm working on a large project and made a relative small contribution: a new class in C++ called by a C code. After adding my contribution to the project, I found that the debugging build works flawlessly, while the release build only fail on ~30 testcases (from a total of 20k+), where some functions of "libucis.so" was called. "valgrind" on the debug and release build of the same code base surprisingly shows a difference: no invalid access was found in the debug build, while it is the case for the release build. Some typical valgrind errors are like below:

```
==220335== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==220335==    at 0x508D17D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==220335==    by 0x5588587: _M_dispose (basic_string.h:2765)
==220335==    by 0x5588587: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:927)
==220335==    by 0x5588A4D: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:1124)
*****some functions of libucsi.so not shown*****

==220335== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==220335==    at 0x508D17D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==220335==    by 0x5589004: _M_dispose (basic_string.h:2765)
==220335==    by 0x5589004: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:951)
*****some functions of libucsi.so not shown*****
```

What's more, I confirmed that my code (class methods in C wrapper) was never called in all failed testcases that reports the similar error above. And all the valgrind invaid access errors happens on the basic_string class in STL.

Regarding my class: a SQLite database writer. Includes vector and string headers.

I have done an extensive search, either online or offline... Some hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please show your code along with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show your C++ class and how it is being called.

Comment: I would look in your code for incorrect use of the internal pointer in some std::string, but without seeing your code, that's a guess. It would also help to know in what way the 30 test cases failed. Segfaults? Or just the wrong behavior. (If a crash, stack trace please.)

Comment: Please show the _complete text_ - no elisions whatsoever - of the _very first_ error reported by valgrind.  What you have posted is almost certainly "fallout" from an earlier invalid memory operation.

Comment: Thank you for all comment above. I made a further investigation and finally located the root cause: the std::string. Whenever I include even a single piece of code related to std::string, like a simple private string definition in my class "std::string dbName", the program crashes. If I clean all std::string in my class declaration and definition, the program passes fluently. But std::string is simply far more handy compared to cstring. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem finally resolved. Here is a summary of the investigation and solution.

After going back and forth for nothing, I decided to test my class with nothing: keep only function members with empty definitions and necessary returns, and comment all "redundant" things. Successfully passed all the remaining ~30 testcases. Then I gradually uncomment my code, eventually I found that the error occur whenever I use std::string, even with a single declaration like "std::string s;". Based on a further search, I believe the problem is due to that "libucis.so" is compiled with a different version stdc++. And I knew that libucis.so is not compiled by us but is supplied by a third party. Then I went back to my makefile, and discarded all unnecessary library/header search paths. The result is that the character count to compile my code is reduced from ~5000 to only 281. Incrementally rebuild the whole project, problem resolved. Phew...

Update: The root cause may be somehow different from the discussion above. Eventually I found that compile my C++11 code with -fPIC solved the problem. But the Q is that the other C codes included in the target are not compiled with -fPIC... So why my C++11 code is the only guy needs to be compiled with -fPIC option, not the remaining (20+ source code files) C codes?